# Get python XLwings user-defined function on Excel to run at regular interval

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Suppose I have this UDF defined in python v3.6 xlwings v0.11 to run on Excel 2016.

```
import xlwings as xw

@xw.func
def random_val(x):
    import random
    return random.random()*x
```

The UDF is imported into an Excel sheet which supports xlwings. I have tested that the formula `=random_val(2)`at cell A1 works fine.

My question is how do I run this UDF at regular time interval of 1 minute so that the output is refreshed at cell A1 every minute.

Comment: Use [application-ontime-method-excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-ontime-method-excel) and reschedule every minute. Related: [OnTime](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx).

Comment: @stovfl, it works for VBA sub procedures. It doesn't work for user-defined functions.

Comment: Have you tried? Do you know this? Unfortunately can't test myself.

Comment: Can't you then create a subroutine that calls the UDF and places it into a cell of your choice?

Comment: Is there a need for python and xlwings?  I would use rnd function in VBA for my UDF and use Application.Volatile. Seems like it can be simplified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done easily through Macros.

```
import xlwings as xw

@xw.sub
def my_macro():
    import time
    import random
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        wb.sheets[0].range('A1').value = random.random()
```

> After clicking on Import Python UDFs, you can then use this macro by executing it via Alt + F8 or by binding it e.g. to a button. To to the latter, make sure you have the Developer tab selected under File > Options > Customize Ribbon. Then, under the Developer tab, you can insert a button via Insert > Form Controls. After drawing the button, you will be prompted to assign a macro to it and you can select my_macro.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not what you are expecting, but it works the way you want it.

Thus, imagine that your function prints the the time in HH:MM:SS like this:

```
Public Function MyTimeMinutesSeconds() As String

    Application.Volatile
    MyTimeMinutesSeconds = Format(Hour(Now), "00") & ":" & _
                           Format(Minute(Now), "00") & ":" & _
                           Format(Second(Now), "00")

End Function
```

Thus, if you recalculate the worksheet every `N` seconds, then the function will be called every `N` seconds and it will be updated. This is how to call it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Sub Starting()

    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    [a1].Formula = "=MyTimeMinutesSeconds()"

    While i < 6
        Sleep (500)
        Calculate
        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

What you get is a nice ticking clock in excel:

[image]

---

The trick is in the `Application.Volatile` part of the function:

*A [volatile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-volatile-method-excel) must be recalculated whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the worksheet. A nonvolatile function is recalculated only when the input variables change. This method has no effect if it's not inside a user-defined function used to calculate a worksheet cell.*

Comment: part I can translate to python using decorators `xlwings.func(category="xlwings", volatile=False, call_in_wizard=True)`

Comment: this locks the code in a sleep call and removes responsiveness.

Comment: @SMeaden - and the other sleep is different?

Comment: @Vityata: `Application.OnTime` retains responsiveness.